# How to place the cursor (auto focus) in text box when a page gets loaded without javascript support?

Tags: css, html

I have a form with some text fields,and I want to place the cursor **(auto focus)** on first text field of form when page gets loaded.

I want to do it without using javascript.

Comment: `<input.... tabindex="1" />`

Answer (score 170):

Ya its possible to do without support of javascript.. 
We can use html5  **auto focus attribute**  
For Example:

```
<input type="text" name="name" autofocus="autofocus" id="xax" />
```

If use it (autofocus="autofocus") in text field means that text field get focused when page gets loaded..
For more details:
http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/html5/autofocus-attribute.html

Comment: The appropriate capitalization is actually autoFocus for JSX/React.

Answer (score 45):

Just add `autofocus` in first input or textarea.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="xax" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

Comment: At least in Chrome, `autofocus` does not work, but `autofocus="autofocus"` does.

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
OnLoad="document.myform.mytextfield.focus();"
```

Comment: @putvande - the title does say "using javascript" so give him a break.

Comment: He said without JavaScript support.

Answer (score 2):

```
<body onLoad="self.focus();document.formname.name.focus()" >

formname is <form action="xxx.php" method="POST" name="formname" >
and name is <input type="text" tabindex="1" name="name" />

it works for me, checked using IE and mozilla.
autofocus, somehow didn't work for me.
```

Comment: The OP said "without javascript".

Answer (score 2):

An expansion for those who did a bit of fiddling around like I did.

The following work (from W3):

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
<input type="text" autofocus="" />
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" />
<input type="text" autofocus="AuToFoCuS" />
```

It is important to note that this does not work in CSS though. I.e. you can't use:

```
.first-input {
    autofocus:"autofocus"
}
```

At least it didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

very easy you can just set the attribute autofocus to  on in the wanted input

```html
<form action="exemple.php"  method="post">
   <input name="wantedInput" autofocus="on">
   <input type="submit" value="go"  >
</form>
```

Answer (score -7):

Sometimes all you have to do to make sure the cursor is inside the text box is:
click on the text box and when a menu is displayed, click on "Format text box"
then click on the "text box" tab and finally modify all four margins (left, right, upper and bottom) by arrowing down until "0" appear on each margin.