# Put cursor in input field after hover

Tags: css, html

I have a form that is `display:none` and when I am going to hover on a another link, then the form comes up. How can I put the cursor into the input field? Is there a way to do it in css?

If I make the form to `display:inline-block` directly, the cursor is in the input field.

My CSS:

```
.search-bar {
    display: none;
 }

 #main-nav a:hover .search-bar {
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

My Form in the html file:

```
<input id="search_search" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Placeholder.Search.Main" name="search[search]"></input>
```

Comment: "I have a form that is display:none and when I am going to hover it" - i don't think you can hover something that is not there.... also `.search-bar` won't target anything in the shared code since you don't have such a class in there...

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: JSFiddle will be useful here

Comment: can you share the html of the above mentioned link and form as well..? btw i don't think you can do this just using css...

Comment: By **"cursor"** you mean **"caret"**, right? If that's the case you can use JS and set dynamically `focus` to a desired element after a  `hover` or any other event.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan *mouse cursor*..? i've heard of *mouse pointer* first time hearing this... :)

Comment: @TilwinJoy https://www.google.hr/search?q=images+cursor&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=nRn&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=LxSnU-mhNbGN0wX9oICgDw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1884&bih=1102

Comment: @TilwinJoy see [css cursor proprety](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan [google mouse pointer](https://www.google.hr/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=fflb&biw=1884&bih=1102&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=images+mouse+pointer&btnG=).

Comment: @TilwinJoy haha i did! :) We call it mainly **Cursor**, while *Pointer* is just a Cursor style, read more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the image for *cursor* in my mind was the blinking line thing in typable areas until now @___@

Comment: @TilwinJoy it took me one whole year to memorize it's real name :) (Happens when English is not your main language :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `HTML5` **auto focus attribute**

For Example:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="search_search" placeholder="Placeholder.Search.Main" name="search[search]" />
```

We can use JQuery to do this using `foxus()`

Javascript:

```
$("#show").hover(function(){
    $("#search_search").show();
    $("#search_search").focus();
});
```

Doesn't work in Firefox but works in Safari

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for some client-side scripting (Javascript or javascript with JQuery).

If you don't want to accomplish this through client-side scripting, and only want to support html5, then you should take a look into the "autofocus" attribute of html5. See the top answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054459/how-to-place-the-cursorauto-focus-in-text-box-when-a-page-gets-loaded-with-out).