# When I open my website I want to move the input to my form (see screen so you know what I mean)

Tags: html, css

When I open my website I want to automatically start typing in my form instead of the default browser search bar.

from the scren:
I want to start typing in the Google bar for example.
[scrn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHZTE.png)

Comment: `document.getElementById('google bar id goes here').focus();`?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054459/how-to-place-the-cursor-auto-focus-in-text-box-when-a-page-gets-loaded-without

Answer (score 1):

There is an `autofocus` attribute in Html 5

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> This Boolean attribute lets you specify that a form control should
>   have input focus when the page loads, unless the user overrides it
>   (e.g. by typing in a different control). Only one form element in a
>   document can have the autofocus attribute, which is a Boolean. It
>   cannot be applied if the type attribute is set to hidden (that is, you
>   cannot automatically set focus to a hidden control). Note that the
>   focusing of the control may occur before the firing of the
>   DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: The only thing worth noting with this one is that you lose compatibility with iOS safari and IE <= 9.